# Query returns no records but phpmyadmin does

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm having trouble querying my database for results. When I enter the query in phpmyadmin, it works perfectly. But executing the exact same query in php returns no results.

I have searched the internet for quite a while now, but everywhere i find this kind of query voted as the best answer. Maybe I missed something and you guys can help me out.

The query:

```
SELECT current_consumption, current_delivery, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) FROM energydata WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include "database.php";

$limit = (int)$_GET["limit"];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $databaseUser, $databasePassword, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT current_consumption, current_delivery, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) FROM energydata WHERE timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$json = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $columns = array(
        array(
            'id' => 'date',
            'label' => 'Date',
            'type' => 'datetime'),
        array(
            'id' => 'consumption',
            'label' => 'Consumption',
            'type' => 'number'),
        array(
            'id' => 'delivery',
            'label' => 'Delivery',
            'type' => 'number')
        );

    $rows = array();

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $date = array();
        $date = date_parse($row['timestamp']);

        $currentRow = array(
            'c' => array(
                array(
                    'v' => 'Date('. $row['UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)'] .'000)'
                ),
                array(
                    'v' => $row['current_consumption']
                ),
                array(
                    'v' => $row['current_delivery']
                )
            )
        );

        array_push($rows, $currentRow);
    }

    $json = array(
        'cols' => $columns,
        'rows' => $rows);
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` in your script after starting `<?php` and checkf or error.also instead of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tijdstempel) ` in your query write `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tijdstempel) as unixtime`  and then instead of  `array(
                    'v' => 'Date('. $row['UNIX_TIMESTAMP(tijdstempel)'] .'000)'
                ),`   write `array(
                    'v' => $row['unixtime'];),`  Also add missing `;` there and check

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but there is no error thrown. The missing `;` is not missing, it is an array in an array, so only a `;` after the initial `array()` is needed.

Comment: You do need better error reporting - but mysqli does not throw errors - you need to poll them. You have checked the connection worked, but if you'd checked for errors after running the query, you might have seen "no database selected"

Answer (score 0):

well it must be some data problem.

Your code works fine here with a small change (look at first var_dump).

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost:3308", "root", "", "testit");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bill_date) FROM bills WHERE bill_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {   
   var_dump($row["UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bill_date)"]);
}
var_dump($result);
```

the output is:

```
string(10) "1489741452" 
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```